# Change sequence of fields in the CSV while exporting it from admin

Tags: magento2, grid

I have a module that exports some data from admin to CSV file. Everything works fine but now I need to rearrange the CSV columns. I need to change the sequence of some fields in the CSV. Here is the screenshot of what is required.

[image]

I need to move the where column to first position in the CSV. In the same way I need to alter the position of different columns too. I would have done it manually but there are 32 columns and doing it daily could take a lot of time. We are using ui component method to export the CSV. SCreenshot

[image]

I tried searching for it but did not find anything. Plz guide me how I can go on arranging the CSV columns according to my need during the export process.

**Update:** The module is using ui_component method to export CSV. There is no ExportCsv.php file

The code that is being used to export csv.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achive via change code from controller

> app\code\Your\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Items

here you can find your export CSV and export XML controller file.

> ExportCsv.php
>
> ExportExcel.php

also sometime defined in block as below path

> app\code\Your\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Items

here you can find your export CSV and export XML controller file.

> ExportCsv.php
>
> ExportExcel.php

in this file you can change your code for change the sequence of some fields in the CSV

hope this helps you :)

Comment: I have updated my question according to your answer. Plz have a look.